# "Her this behavior" vs "this behavior of her"

Tags: sentence-construction, syntax

Suppose a girl did something wrong that showed us her real face. Now if I want to say that I don't like her behavior, how do I say?

1. I don't like her this behavior
2. I don't like this behavior of her.

In the first sentence, I feel that "this" and "her" next to each other sound unnatural (two modifiers) while sentence no. 2 is verbose and does not sound very natural to me.

By "this", I mean the current behavior, the one she is acting at **this** time.

Is there any other way to say that?

Comment: Sentence 1 is indeed wrong. Use either "this" or "her", but not both. Sentence 2 is nearly right, but you need "hers" instead of her. (Or mine, yours, his, theirs). Or maybe "I don't like the way she is behaving", which refers to current behaviour.

Comment: _"I don't like what she's doing."_

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should omit 'this' in the first sentence

1. I don't like her behavior

but that would be about her behavior *in general*.

2. I don't like this behavior of hers.

(note the extra 's' at the end – it's a [double genitive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20genitive)) may feel verbose, but it's very natural and refers to more specific behavior, so it may be closest to what you want to express. Otherwise, you can also go for

3. I don't like her current behavior.

though 'current' usually refers to something that's going on *right now*; perhaps 'recent' works better in your context.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought of replacing "this" with any other word like "current". ;)

Comment: "You can omit 'this'" - I think that's a bit of an understatement. You *should* omit 'this', otherwise it sounds quite unnatural (to me, at least) and is possibly grammatically just wrong.

Comment: @NotThatGuy yes, it *is* grammatically wrong. I assumed the OP already discarded that sentence and I'm just showing how they *can* correct it.

Comment: @Glorfindel Please can you change "can" to "should" as NotThatGuy suggested. Your answer currently reads to me like you're saying "I don't like her this behavior" is _fine_ and removal is _optional_. Or be explicit with say "You can omit 'this' in the first sentence to make it natural".

Comment: I’ll be so bold as to put words into Glorfindel’s mouth and suggest that he meant «You can omit 'this' in the first sentence (leaving “I don't like her behavior”) ***or*** you can omit 'her' (leaving “I don't like this behavior”), *but you **must** do one of those.*»